# I am working on react js and using session storage . As i open a new tab data is getting clear

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on React JS application. Here, I have used session storage.

When user get logged in then we are storing user id in session storage... this works fine

but when I open the application url in another tab then user is not logged in

he get logged out

Comment: Yes, that's how session storage works.

Answer (score 4):

sessionStorage is linked to a particular tab. Once the tab is closed the stored data is deleted.
If you want the data to persist in browser memory you can use localStorage